# How to open .rec files created by ATI VISION software?

Tags: file-conversion

How to open .rec files created by [ATI VISION software](http://www.accuratetechnologies.com/content/view/240/237/lang,en/)?  I want to get the data points out and analyze it in other software.

Comment: No.  But it's not a multimedia file so i didn't even think that possibility.  What makes you think VLC could work?

Comment: @PhillipR.: Just because some programs use overlapping extensions does not make the files the same format. In VLC's case it's a video recording, possibly from a PVR.

Comment: @PhillipR.: I thought he mentioned that ATI Vision is the software that created the files, and from its site it looks like it can open them as well to allow data analysis. IMO it's obvious that he's looking for insight into the file's format, so that he can parse it using other (free?) software (or maybe write something to do so himself).

Comment: @Karan, I just want to use some free or alternative softwares to open those files, so i can look at them and possibly copy them out.

Answer (score 0):

.rec files are in a proprietary format for ATI VISION. They can be unzipped to a binary format for translation, but it's not straightforward.

The easiest way is to use ATI VISION which has a built in File Converter to output them as either .csv or .MAT files for use in other applications. The program can also automatically convert a .rec file to either of those formates when it is generated from one of the logging objects in VISION.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This is a 6 yr old question, and you're the first to provide an answer, so kudos.  The OP's link to ATI Vision now just goes to a generic site link, so information on the product would take some research.  It isn't clear whether this is free software.  The OP implies in a comment that they may have the files but not the software, so they were looking for a way to open the files without having to purchase ATI Vision if it isn't free.  Are you able to shed light on that?  (cont'd)

Comment: If that software is free or really cheap, one suggestion to make this answer even better would be to include brief instructions on how to use the built in converter to do this.